# Solution for compiling SCSS and deploying to remote server

Tags: css, webpack, sass, gulp, gruntjs

We are in need of a solution to compile SCSS and deploy to a remote server.

We have tried using both Grunt and Gulp setups but it appears that the FTP plugins for both are no longer compatible with newer versions of Grunt/Gulp.

We have also tried WebPack today which we like, but we're not sure how to deploy the compiled files.

We are needing to do it this way as it takes too long to download a copy of a clients site, make a small style change locally and reupload. We do want the benefits of using sass therefore we need a local solution to compile our styles and then deploy them to a specified folder on the server.

Our ideal workflow would be to make a change to a scss file (JS in the near future), a background task would see the change, compile it to css and another tasks would see that and deploy it to the correct remote folder.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Neil

Comment: Use node-sass + node js. You can compile from the command line and use node to do deploying. You don't have to use anything else ;)

Answer (score 0):

A small example of how you can recompile scss to css and upload to the server via ftp
Folder structure below and the normal call to `node indes.js` and that's it ;)

```
.
├── index.js
├── output.css
├── package.json
├── style.scss
└── yarn.lock
```

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const sass = require('node-sass');
const ftp = require("basic-ftp")

const pathTotheFile = './output.css';

// compile scss
sass.render({
  file: __dirname + './style.scss',
  outputStyle: 'compressed',
  outFile: __dirname + pathTotheFile,
  // sourceMap: true,
}, function (error, result) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error.status);
    console.log(error.column);
    console.log(error.message);
    console.log(error.line);
  } else {

    console.log(result.stats);
    fs.writeFile(pathTotheFile, result.css, function (err) {
      if (!err) {
        uploadCSStoServer();
      }
    })
  }
});

// copy file to server
async function uploadCSStoServer() {
  const client = new ftp.Client()
  client.ftp.verbose = true
  try {
    await client.access({
      host: "myftpserver.com",
      user: "very",
      password: "password",
      secure: true
    })
    console.log(await client.list())
    await client.uploadFrom("README.md", "README_FTP.md")
    // await client.downloadTo("README_COPY.md", "README_FTP.md")
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
  client.close()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  I think i'd prefer something using Grunt/Gulp, as then I can set up tasks for JS and other items in the future.  My issue is;t really with the compilation of things it's the getting them to the server. I know Grunt/Gulp can watch directories for specific file types but the only FTP plugins for them appear to have been deprecated or don't support SFTP. Are there any alternatives or other ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately, I will not help you with gulp, I switched to webpack ages ago, but from what I remember in gulp you can run an external script so you can run an external script with node-sass after compilation.